# How to log errors on Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I do know you can do `heroku logs` and `heroku logs --source app --num 1500` to access logs.

Is that supposed to be the real way to access important error logs?

That would make little sense because heroku logs every single GET requests. As soon as someone logs on the website, all important logs get overwritten by router logs so I can't access them anymore.

Am I missing something?

Note: I am not looking for a solution to minimize the amount of GET requests my website does.

Comment: There are tools like [logentries](https://logentries.com/) that allow to preserve and view logs  remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer is this: for long-term log storage / archival / reporting, you need to export your Heroku logs somewhere else. Heroku has a built in way to do this via syslog drains: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains

You can either write your own log drain to store logs in S3 / your own server, or you could use one of the many Heroku logging addons that are available for a small fee: https://addons.heroku.com/#logging

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a tool like Papertrail or Logentries to drain your full logs into a searchable, archive-able format.